Login button flickering on page reload in zustand/react
I have this auth zustand store:
import { create } from "zustand";
import { persist } from "zustand/middleware";

type AuthStore = {
  isLogged: boolean;
  login: () => void;
  logout: () => void;
};

export const useAuthStore = create<AuthStore>()(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      isLogged: false,
      login: () => set({ isLogged: true }),
      logout: () => set({ isLogged: false }),
    }),
    {
      name: "authStore",
    },
  ),
);

the login button code:
const isLogged = useAuthStore(state=> state.isLogged)
return (
{!isLogged ? <LoginBtn/> : <UserPic/>
)

problem is even though it is persisted, there is this annoying flicker of the login button on page reload:
the flicker
What i am trying to have is to make it stop that flickering.

I've not used "zustand", but it looks like on the initial load isLogged is false. Assuming your system does something on initial load to authenticate the user, perhaps add an initial null state for isLogged to act as a "pending authentication", then you can use that to display e.g. a loading spinner, or empty space until you have the real value.

Changing the intial value of the isLogged state to null as @DBS said fixes that flickering problem
import { persist } from "zustand/middleware";

type AuthStore = {
  isLogged: boolean | null;
  login: () => void;
  logout: () => void;
};

export const useAuthStore = create<AuthStore>()(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      isLogged: null,
      login: () => set({ isLogged: true }),
      logout: () => set({ isLogged: false }),
    }),
    {
      name: "authStore",
    },
  ),
);

